# Bootstrap Carousel Image Comrpessed when Screen is Small

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do i make my image work like

```
http://graduateland.com/
```

I tried following their css, i'm currently using bootstrap 3 carousel.

My Current Code

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
min-width: 100%;
height: 500px;
}
```

GraduateLand

```
[id="get-started"] {
display: table;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin-top: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
background-image: url("/newgl/gateway/gl/img/home-hero.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-size: 100%;

id="get-started"] {
background-size: auto;
background-position: center top;
}
```

Updated

```
element.style {
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer~

```
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #000 url('URLEREE) no-repeat;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-color: transparent;
```

Answer (score -1):

for showing full width image on header :

```
<div class="header">

<div class="container">
<!-- put carousel here -->   >
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I'm not so interested in showing the full image but to show part of the image when the screen size is shorten. Currently it looks ugly when screen size is small because the image is cmopressed

Comment: background-size: cover

Comment: I updated the question .. must it be in a div or can it be in a img element